# update value of element stored in 2 different lists

Tags: python

Say I have some variable `x=2` and it is stored in 2 lists in different slots:

`a=[1,x,3]` and `b=[x,6,7,8]`

When I print `a` and `b` I get: `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[2,6,7,8]`

But if I now set `x=0`, printing  `a` and `b` still gives `a=[1,2,3]` and `b=[2,6,7,8]`

I would like to get: `a=[1,0,3]` and `b=[0,6,7,8]`

Is this possible in Python 2.7? If it is, please also describe its limits in terms of other data types, such as sets, arrays, tuples, and so on.

Thank you!

Comment: It's not possible. When you use the variable in an expression, its value is used, it doesn't save a reference to the variable.

Comment: I don't often see duplicates of questions that are barely more than half an hour old.